# Merge Multiple Documents and Convert to One Pdf in LibreOffice from Terminal

Tags: server, libreoffice, pdf

In my Ubuntu Server 12.04, I am converting all .docx files under a directory to .pdf files with this command:

```
libreoffice -headless -convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export *.docx
```

Can I merge multiple documents and convert them to single .pdf file like this?

For example:

```
file1.docx
file2.docx
file3.docx
```

And the output should be one .pdf file like `merged_result.pdf`. I have to do it from Terminal because I'm using it in PHP.

Furthermore, can I add picture like front image?  Any kind of source I can get the Terminal functions for LibreOffice is appreciated, too; I was unable to find what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you could use an additional tool, like [pdftk](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pdftk/) for instance, to do the merging part. You could then chain the two commands; the first one with Libreoffice, the second one with pdftk.

Comment: I just was wondering if I could solve it with only one comment/plugin. Thanks, I tried pdftk and it's working good(I tried .docx, .xlsx and .jpg so far). One more question, do you know a way to add line numbers? Neither using LibreOffice nor pdftk.

Comment: No I don't. Please consider opening new question. By the way, I think I should say this to you: don't forget to upvote good answers, eventually in addition to marking as accepted. I see that here on Stack Overflow you barely do it. It gives points to the answerer, which is an indicator for community trust and a mean to get more privileges on a Stack Exchange website. Do you see what I mean ?

Answer (score 0):

1. First, we install **pdftk** (there is no need of LibreOffice)

   ```
   sudo apt-get install pdftk -y
   ```
2. Rename your source files in the correct order, for example:

   ```
   01-cover.pdf
   02-summary.pdf
   03-content.pdf
   ```
3. Now let's build our output file using the terminal. **right-click >> open terminal here**. Now type

   ```
   pdftk *.pdf output "full-book.pdf"
   ```

For more explanation, please read `man pdftk`.